# How to set asp Panel element visible/hidden with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, panel

I have a `asp:Panel` element on my page. I'm able to set its visibility in code behind. But I need to also hide it through javascipt.

My `panel` is defined as following:

```
     <asp:Panel ID="pnlUpdateDisplay" runat="server" Visible="false" style="width:500px; border-width: thick;">
        <table style="width:300px;">
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" style="width:120px" align="center">
                <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateMessage" runat="server" style="position:absolute; left: 120px; top: 120px;"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>      
    </asp:Panel>
```

When I do this:

```
   var panel = document.getElementById('pnlUpdateDisplay');
   panel.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   panel.style.display='none';
```

There is an error saying: **"Error: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined"**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Paste your generated html in your question

Comment: Actually, for some reason, there is not generated html for panel and other elements on a page but I'm able to see them on a page

Comment: @eugene.it, just noticed that the panel has `Visible=false`. ASP.NET would not render it at all

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Setting `Visible=false` to the server control in ascx/aspx mark up or
>   in a code behind prevent the control being rendered in DOM. So you
>   will not find them in DOM and it won't be accessible to JavaScript

Better **remove** `Visible="false"` set in the panel and add style `display:none`.

If you want to make it in code behind follow this code

```
pnlUpdateDisplay.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display,"none");
```

Then use

```
$('#<%=pnlUpdateDisplay.ClientID %>').toggle()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.toggle()` to toggle between show and hide:

```
$('#pnlUpdateDisplay').toggle();
```

If you want to hide it only then use `.hide()`

```
$('#pnlUpdateDisplay').hide();
```